# Android - searchable activity, transaction has to press back twice

Tags: android, search

In my app I use the same activity (with `launchMode="singleTop"`) for search results that is querying the search.

In my `handleIntent()` I show fragment for search results:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        SearchResultsFragment searchFrag = new SearchResultsFragment();

        searchFrag.setQuery(query);
        searchFrag.update();

        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.pager, searchFrag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Problem is I have to press back button twice for transaction to be reversed (or up button on action bar and then device's back button). Why is that? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is the activity is pushed to back stack along with the fragment as you have used transaction.addToBackStack(null); which will cause fragment to also contribute to the back stack, removing this line should fix your issue.